# Select products and join categories hierarchical

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables in my database:

```
create table category (id integer, name text, parent_id integer);
create table product (id integer, name text, category integer, description text);

insert into category
        values
        (1, 'Category A', null),
        (2, 'Category B', null),
        (3, 'Category C', null),
        (4, 'Category D', null),
        (5, 'Subcategory Of 1', 1),
        (6, 'Subcategory Of 5', 5),
        (7, 'Subcategory Of 5', 5),
        (8, 'Subcategory of D', 4)
        ;

insert into product
        values
        (1, 'Product One', 5, 'Our first product'),
        (2, 'Product Two', 6, 'Our second product'),
        (3, 'Product Three', 8, 'The even better one');
```

How can I return like this:

```
product_id | product_name | root_category | category_path               
-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------
         1 | Product One  |             1 | /Category A/Subcategory Of 1
         2 | Product Two  |             1 | /Category A/Subcategory of 5/Subcategory of 6
```

I use "WITH RECURSIVE" in categories table but can't find the way to combine product table with 1 time query.
I use example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909550/select-all-products-and-join-main-category-through-sub-categories-unknown-level/39910725#39910725)

What's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, assumming you have MariaDB 10.2 or newer:

```
with recursive pt (root_id, id, path) as (
  select id, id, concat('/', name) from category where parent_id is null
  union all
  select pt.root_id, c.id, concat(pt.path, '/', c.name) 
    from pt join category c on c.parent_id = pt.id
)
select p.id, p.name, pt.root_id, pt.path
  from pt
  join product p on pt.id = p.category;
```

Result:

```
id  name            root_id  path                                                
--  --------------  -------  ---------------------------------------------
1   Product One     1        /Category A/Subcategory Of 1
2   Product Two     1        /Category A/Subcategory Of 1/Subcategory Of 5
3   Product Three   4        /Category D/Subcategory of D
```

Comment: where can I put statemen 'WHERE product.id' because i want combine with PHP

Comment: Just append it at then end. The last section is just a normal `SELECT`.